# Расставьте знаки препинания в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Но на самом деле рассуждая на извечную тему о том чем же всё-таки необходимо руководствоваться в жизни чувствами или разумом мы не можем дать однозначного ответа.

Comment: Хоть один-то знак поставьте сами, Ксения Молодцова!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие, т.к. ДЗ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Но на самом деле**, рассуждая на извечную тему о том, чем же всё-таки необходимо руководствоваться в жизни ― чувствами или разумом, **мы не можем дать однозначного ответа.**

**Пояснение**

Содержание местоименного союзного слова ЧЕМ раскрывается с помощью  **обособленного приложения** "чувствами или разумом". Конструкция встроенная (не вставка), поэтому второе тире **"поглощается" запятой.**